# MYSQL TRIGGER (BEFORE INSERT) gives me NULL

Tags: mysql, join, select, triggers, insert

please I have a probleme with MYSQL TRIGGER :

```
CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT ON `table_A` 
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.name = (SELECT `table_B`.`name` FROM `table_A` INNER JOIN `table_B` 
ON `table_A`.`table_B_id` = `table_B`.`id` WHERE `table_A`.`id` = NEW.id);
```

So I need that col name in table_A fill from table_B using the NEW.id in join.
it's like the NEW.id is NULL so that col fill with NULL
any ideas
and thank you in advance

Comment: is table_A`.`id` an auto_increment column

Comment: yes, table_A.id is an auto_increment column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no reason to include table_A in the select or WHERE `table_A`.`id` = NEW.id)

```
SET NEW.name = (SELECT `table_B`.`name` FROM `table_B` 
ON new.`table_B_id` = `table_B`.`id` );
```

If this doesn't work for you add sample data and expected output as text to the question